# wpdb->insert into custom wp table using prepare()

Tags: mysql, insert, wordpress, prepare

Working on a time system in Wordpress and run into something strange problem with wp insert when inserting to a custom table.

I am running the following function in my functions.php

```
function clock_in() {

if ( isset( $_POST['punch-in'] ) && '1' == $_POST['punch-in'] ) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
                    "
                        INSERT INTO $wpdb->wp_diss_users_sessions
                        (session_id,session_begin)
                        VALUES ( %d, %s )
                    ", 
                        $user_id,'test' 

) );
```

I've tested the function with an update query to wp_users table to verify the function is firing appropriately as desired.

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'(session_id,session_begin) VALUES ( 2, 'test' )' at line 2]
INSERT INTO (session_id,session_begin) VALUES ( 2, 'test' )
```

My Table is designed as such:

```
[session_id] - INT(11) PK NN
[session_begin] - VARCHAR(45)
```

I understand best practice is to use prepare so I am trying to build all of my queries appropriately.  I do believe $wpdb->wp_diss_users_sessions  = correct syntax to reference my custom table from researching.  Maybe I'm overlooking something simple but my head hurts for tonight.

Thanks all

Comment: The table name is missing in the query.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-wpdb-gt-to-access-a-custom-table It's basically the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you don't have a table name in your query:

```
INSERT INTO (session_id,session_begin) VALUES ( 2, 'test' )
            ^ here should be a table name
```

Just using `$wpdb->wp_diss_users_sessions` will not work, your table name will not appear magically inside the wpdb object. You have to store it there yourself.

In [this thread in the WordPress support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-wpdb-gt-to-access-a-custom-table) it is suggested to add this in a function of your plugin/theme:

```
$wpdb->myplugintable = $table_prefix . 'myplugintable';
```

If you place this in a function, don't forget to pull `$table_prefix` inside its scope with the `global` keyword.

Afterwards you can access the table name in the manner you intend.